# Restarting Tomcat after a successful deployment with Jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, restart

How can I have Jenkins restart a Tomcat instance after a successful deployment?

I already tried using a batch script, but the Tomcat instance is killed when the build is finished.

Comment: When are you running the batch script? If you do it after "Post-build events", it should work.

Answer (score 9):

Your answer lies in [**Jenkins ProcessTreeKiller**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller). A [**more detailed explanation here**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build).

It's a design decision to kill any processes that are spawned by the build to maintain a clean environment. Unfortunately that means you can't leave a process (such as Tomcat) running after the build.

You can disable this functionality globally (not recommended) by launching Jenkins like this:
`java -Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true -jar jenkins.war`

Or you can disable this on a per-case basis, by launching the process with a changed environment variable:
`BUILD_ID=dontKillMe ./catalina restart`

Some people report however that changing `BUILD_ID` is not enough. They recommend also unsetting:
`JENKINS_COOKIE`
`JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE`

***Edit:***
Another issue that could be at play is that when you connect to remote shell, and start a process in that remote shell session, once you (Jenkins) disconnects, the session is killed and all processes spawned by the session are killed too. To get around that issue, you need to disassociate the process from the shell session.

One way is:

`nohup ./catalina restart &`

Comment: I have already used the Jenkins ProcessTreeKiller withouth success.  When I started Jenkins with this parameter, I noticed no difference on the behaviour of spawned processes.

Comment: Are you connecting to remote shell? Edited the answer to take remote shell into account

Comment: Ah! The edited part is the crucial step for remote script execution. I was scratching my head a lot thinking why tomcat is not starting while shutdown was working properly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am restarting Tomcat after deployment via jenkins.

I am having two servers DEV and QA where I need to do the deployment and restart tomcat. I have Jenkins installed in DEV server.

1. First you need to install [Post build task](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Post+build+task) Plugin in Jenkins.
2. Then create this script `tomcat-restart.ksh` in the server where you have tomcat installed..

`#!/bin/bash
echo "*********************Restarting Tomcat70.******************"
sh /apps/apache/sss-tomcat70.ksh status
echo "Trying to stop Tomcat."
sh /apps/apache/sss-tomcat70.ksh stop
echo "Getting Tomcat Status."
sh /apps/apache/sss-tomcat70.ksh status
echo "Trying to Start Tomcat"
sh /apps/apache/sss-tomcat70.ksh start
sleep 2
echo "Getting Tomcat Status"
sh /apps/apache/sss-tomcat70.ksh status`

> Restarting Tomcat on DEV server.

Since Jenkins and Tomcat is installed in the same machine I am directly calling the script.

In Jenkins go to `Add post-build action` and choose `Post build task` and in the `Script` textbox add the following : `/apps/apache/tomcat-restart.ksh`

> Restarting Tomcat in QA server.

Since Jenkins is installed in different server, I am calling the script to restart Tomcat via Secure Shell.

In Jenkins go to Add `post-build action` select `Post build task` and in the Script textbox add the following : 
`sshpass -p 'myPassword' ssh -tt username@hostname sudo sh /apps/apache/tomcat-restart.ksh`

You need to install `sshpass` if its not already installed.

If everything went fine, then you may see something like this in your Jenkins log.

```
Running script  : /apps/apache/tomcat-restart.ksh
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson43653169595828207.sh

+ /apps/apache/tomcat-restart.ksh
*********************Restarting Tomcat70.*********************
Tomcat v7.0 is running as process ID 3552
*********************Trying to stop Tomcat.*********************
Stopping Tomcat v7.0 running as process ID 3552...
*********************Getting Tomcat Status.*********************
Tomcat v7.0 is not running
*********************Trying to Start Tomcat*********************
Starting Tomcat v7.0 server...

*********************Getting Tomcat Status*********************
Tomcat v7.0 is running as process ID 17969
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In some version of Jenkins "JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE" not working so in that case u can use "JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE".

Ex:
JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe