# Tomcat startup script not working when invoked from jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, tomcat, jenkins

There are two tomcat instances. One for jenkins(tomcat8-jenkins) and one for the application(tomcat-mc). They are in the same server.

When I execute the shell script in build setup from jenkins it seems like the jenkins is trying to start it's own tomcat instance. following is the script and the error.

```
cd $TOMCAT_PATH/bin
./shutdown.sh

./startup.sh
```

**ERROR**

```
+ cd /usr/local/tomcat-mc/bin
+ ./shutdown.sh
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:216)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:391)

+ ./startup.sh
PID file (/usr/local/tomcat8-jenkins/logs/tomcat.pid) found. Is Tomcat still running? Start aborted.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I've tried unsettling BUILD_ID= and changing CATALINA_HOME=$TOMCAT_PATH . But still the error comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason here was jenkins tomcat has set the CATALINA_BASE. After resetting that to desired tomcat base issue was resolved. Hope it may help somebody in need.
In my case added this to build shell script in jenkins which overides the jenkins tomcat CATALINA_BASE

> export CATALINA_BASE=/usr/local/tomcat-mc

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to you..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28938556/4595123