# ANTRUN_NOHUP works with maven, but doesn't work when i execute from jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm trying to build a Jenkins job to shutdown tomcat, update war and restart tomcat again. I'm working with maven to get the new war. When I execute maven directly from the server, the maven process finishes and the tomcat process is still alive.
But for some reason, whenever I try to execute maven from Jenkins the tomcat process dies together with the Jenkins.

I tried accomplishing this task with a different tool, but it resulted in the same behavior.

Below is my current maven; would love to get some help around it, or get another suggestion on how to implement.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.maven-antrun-extended-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-extended-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-optional</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>20020829</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>promote-from-existing-env-ant</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <property environment="env"/>
                    <exec
                            dir="${tomcat-path}bin"
                            executable="${tomcat-path}bin/shutdown.sh"
                            failonerror="false">                                        
                        <env key="PATH" path="${env.PATH}:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin"/>
                    </exec>
                    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" dir="${tomcat-path}webapps/${war.name}" />
                    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" file="${tomcat-path}webapps/${war.name}.war" />
                    <copy todir="${tomcat-path}webapps" overwrite="true" verbose="true">
                        <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/war/"></fileset>
                    </copy>
                   <exec
                            dir="${tomcat-path}bin"
                            executable="${tomcat-path}bin/startup.sh"
                            failonerror="false" >
                            <env key="PATH" path="${env.PATH}:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin"/>
                            <env key="ANTRUN_NOHUP" value="true" />
                   </exec>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got my answer, had to add BUILD_ID=dontKillMe ./catalina restart

as described here

[Restarting Tomcat after a successful deployment with Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278117/restarting-tomcat-after-a-successful-deployment-with-jenkins)